# file_exists() for a file that contains (&) in filename

Tags: php, algorithm, character, filenames, file-exists

```
$filename = "Sara & I.mp3";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
 ...
}
```

If the filename has a "`&`" PHP does not return true for `file_exists`

How can I escape "`&`" in the $filename for the `file_exists` to work?

Already tried `urlecode()`, `urlrawencode()`, `htmlentities()`, and escaping the '&' with a backslash (\&)... no go

ps. this is on a linux system running RedHat5

thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't answer you question, but that "test-and-perform-action" pattern leaves your code open to race conditions. It's possible that someone could delete the file after you call `file_exists` but before you call `filesize`. Also, the mere fact that the file exists does not mean that you have permission to access it. Your code will be more robust if you remove the `file_exists` call and instead be prepared for `filesize` to fail.

Comment: Getting back to your question, it sounds like you aren't properly escaping/unescaping `$path`. Where does this variable come from?

Comment: Correct can't argue with that :) This code however is merely taken from a wordpress plugin which I am not the original author of...

Comment: I try it and it sees to have no problem. So it must be something else. What is the file system you are using? What is the exact file name? Give use more info.

Comment: @NawaMan, what did you try exactly? you tried to file_exists on a file that included the "&" character in its filename?

Comment: Right (also `filesize`), I created a file with '`&`' in it and it has absolutely no problem on my machine. This shows that those two functions work. So it must be something else.

Comment: I tried this and it worked fine.  I'm wondering if it has to do with the path.  What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I tried it also on debian, no problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script seems to work for me.

Make sure that the file you're checking is in the directory where your script is run.

use getcwd() to see where your script is running.

e.g. if your script is in my/scripts/script.php
but if it's included and invoked by another script at my/other/scripts/index.php then your script would actually be running in the my/other/scripts directory, NOT in the my/scripts directory as you might expect

Answer (score 3):

Are these files uploaded by users? I normally rename any uploaded file to use only letters A-Z, numbers 0-9 and _ or - plus the file extension like .pdf in order to avoid problems with special charachters. Spaces are converted to _.

TYPO3, a large PHP based CMS for example uses these regex in order to clean a filename:

```
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^.[:alnum:]_-]/','_',trim($fileName));  // converting all on alphanumeric chars to _
$fileName = preg_replace('/\.*$/','',$fileName); // removing dot . after file extension
```

So a input of `foo&.pdf.` would be converted to `foo.pdf`

Comment: I'd like to solve this question without the need of renaming files. Thanks Max :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a file, shouldn't be escape as the filesystem expects it to be?  Shouldn't it be something along the lines of \&  or maybe the unicode based escape sequence (which escapes me at the moment ;-) ?

Answer (score 1):

i assume you are passing your parameters as GET requests like `script.php?file=this & that.mp3`

first be sure you check your input really well, so users can't delete arbitrary files. second: encode your filenames with [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) when creating the link. the encoded char for `&` is `%26`.

your script would be called like this then: `script.php?file=this%20%26%20that.mp3` (`%20` being a whitespace)

otherwise you will have another GET variable, namely `that.mp3`, being not assigned. `&` is used to separate single parameters in your GET request

**edit**
a question from my side: how do you delete your files? using php’s `unlink` function? or using `exec` and calling `rm` on your system? (which is generally very unsafe). if you’re doing it the second way you could use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg). if you don’t escape your shell input, your shell will interpret your command as two commands (afaik, don’t take my word for it)

Comment: no, not passing it through GET requests. 

try doing this, create a file and put whatever in it (any txt or whatever) and rename it to "this&that.whatever" then try and see if file_exists works 

ps. this is on a linux based system

Comment: just tested. works for me. `unlink('this&that.test'); (also on a linux system)

Answer (score 0):

Where is the ampersand coming from - user input or is it really inside your script? There may be a mix-up in encodings there.

Also, when you do a glob() on the directory, what results do you get? Is the file with the ampersand there? What happens if you copy & paste the glob() output and run file_exists() on it?